# How to load shape drawable in compose image

Tags: android-drawable, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set a shape drawable to an image in compose, the drawable look like this
*cureved_rect.xml*

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    
        <solid android:color="#FBCCBD" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

I try the below snipet to load the shape

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cureved_rect),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier =  Modifier
            .padding(32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .constrainAs(image) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            })
```

But it is not working, the app crash with an exception *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Only VectorDrawables and rasterised asset types are supported ex PNG,JPG*
1 . How to load shape drawable in compose
2 . Load colour resource  in the compose image

Comment: Why should you load a shape drawable in Compose? You can use the Shape function. Also what is the goal to load a color res in a compose image?

Answer (score 14):

The best solution is to use the [**`Shape`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Shape) provided by Compose.

Something like:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(Color(0xFFFBCCBD), shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
)
```

Otherwise if you want to use drawable resource you can use the [`coil-compose`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#jetpack-compose) version:

Something like:

```
Image(
    rememberImagePainter( ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.shape)),
    contentDescription = "Background",
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp) 
)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add reference links too. I am unable to refer to 'shape' inside Box.

Comment: @AjithMA the shape is inside the [background](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).background(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) Modifier

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround, instead of using **Image** composable function,
you can use **AndroidView** so your code would be similar to this:

```kotlin
    AndroidView(factory = {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(it).inflate(R.layout.temp_layout, null, false)
        view 
                          }, 
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .constrainAs(image) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            })
```

And you will add a temp layout like this 
**temp_layout.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cureved_rect"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Please don't actually do this. Unless you have very strong reasons, there are a lot of other options for Jetpack Compose, e.g. a `Surface` with a shape or drawing directly on the canvas. Performance will definitely be better doing this the Compose way and there will be a lot less overhead :)

Comment: @jossiwolf you're definitely right, but as I said it's a workaround, not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this:

```
@Composable
fun RoundedCornerShapeDemo() {
    ImageResource(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
}

@Composable
fun ImageResource(shape: Shape) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val image: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        Image(painter = image, contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier
            .size(90.dp)
            .clip(shape))
    }
}
```

In your activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ShapeImageApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    RoundedCornerShapeDemo()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```